# Is there a way to resume code within a for next after exutubg a sub

Tags: excel

well I have the following code

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
For i = 1 To 52
For j = 2 To 53
For k = 5 To 57
If Sheets("sheet1").Range("b2").Value <> Sheets("sheet2").Range("b2").Value Then Exit Sub
If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b2").Value = i Then Range("A2:D2").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets(k).Select
    Range("a1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets(k).Range("d16").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-13]c:R[-1]C)"
    Range("d16").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Cells(j, 2).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
i = i + 1
j = j + 1
k = k + 1
Next k
Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

I a trying to create a loop that ignores carrying out a routine if the value of a cell is not of a specific value

the problem is that of course if i<>the value then I leave the for next without the value of i,j and k increasing. Is there anyway of re-entering the code just before the i = i+1, j=j+1 and k=k+1 then going onto the next value of i,j and k. It has been doing my head in for a couple of hours. I tried using an error handler but I think that is useful to skip lines of code anyone help please!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this..

```
Sheets("Sheet" & trim(str(k))).Range("d16").Select
```

I hope this will work...

Comment: if you do not want to use label eh:, you can use...
On Error Resume Next